# Why use setup method for test suites in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working through `railstutorial.org` and in our first test suite we setup an instance variable in a `setup` method.

```
require 'test_helper'

class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  end

  test "should get home" do
    get static_pages_home_url
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Home | #{@base_title}"
  end

  test "should get help" do
    get static_pages_help_url
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Help | #{@base_title}"
  end

  test "should get about" do
    get static_pages_about_url
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "About | #{@base_title}"
  end
end
```

Why do we do this instead of just defining it straight up as an instance variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining it as an instance variable. When the test is run the class (`StaticPagesControllerTest`) is *instantiated* and the setup function called on that instance, not on the class. If you tried to do the following instead it would define a class level instance variable not accessible from instances:

```
class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  @base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"

  test "should get home" do
    get static_pages_home_url
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Home | #{@base_title}" # XXX not defined on instance
  end
...
```

See [this page](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/) for one explanation of the difference.

You could use a class variable (`@@base_title`) but that might cause surprising consequences later, e.g. if you wanted to subclass the test.

Here's a quick demonstration:

```
class First
  @a = 'hoge'
  @@b = 'hoge'

  def initialize
    @c = 'hoge'
  end

  def give_me_a
    @a
  end

  def give_me_b
    @@b
  end

  def give_me_c
    @c
  end
end

f = First.new
# => #<First:0x007fb81607fcd0>
f.give_me_a
# => nil
f.give_me_b
# => "hoge"
f.give_me_c
# => "hoge"
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean that if I tried to run the code block you posted it would defined a class level instance variable not accessible from instances. From what I can tell it is an instance variable accessible by each different instance (a different copy everytime) isn't it?